# Append array element to String(Swift)

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, key

I am trying to make an array of random numbers for an ID for 25 people so I figured that would be the easiest way would use a array map but is there a way to take each element and attach it to an "email" in the dictionary key.

```
class ClassRosterModel {

var randomArray = (1...25).map{_ in arc4random()}


var studentsRoster = [Dictionary<String, String>] ()
init () {

    studentsRoster.append(["name": "Kacz, Alex", "major" : "SE", "email" : ".join(randomArray[0])@email.edu", "currentTerm" : "Spring", "numberOfCredits" : "" ])
    studentsRoster.append(["name": "O'Rore, Ryan", "major" : "SE", "email" : ".join(randomArray[0]@email.edu", "currentTerm" : "Fall", "numberOfCredits" : "" ])

        }

}
```

Comment: Does `randomArray` exist soley to be "injected" into those e-mails? Do you need to keep it aorund after?

Comment: P.s. Those dictionaries should really be `Student` structs.

Comment: just for those emails but i am having trouble trying to make those random numbers atleast 6 digits long so if i happen to get the ID of 000234 it doesn't just come out as 234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I am understanding, you want to put a value inside a string. You can use `\()`.

Example:

```
let value = 101
let email = "myname\(value)@email.com"
print(email)
```

The console result will be:

```
myname101@email.com
```

Just use your randomArray instead of value. And save the email inside your dictionary.

```
studentsRoster.append(["name": "Kacz, Alex", "major" : "SE", "email" : ".join\(randomArray[0])@email.edu", "currentTerm" : "Spring", "numberOfCredits" : "" ])
studentsRoster.append(["name": "O'Rore, Ryan", "major" : "SE", "email" : ".join\(randomArray[0])@email.edu", "currentTerm" : "Fall", "numberOfCredits" : "" ])
```